# Continuous inverse function theorem and open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse

I am trying to use this Continuous Inverse Function Theorem to do the last part of both questions (marked with orange)

Theorem 6.1 is for closed interval. How would I change this to make it work for open intervals as given in Q4 and Q5?

I've managed to do the other parts of the questions. Could anyone please prove the last bits involving open intervals? It would be true if it was for closed interval as I can use Theorem 6.1.

How would I rigorously make it work for open intervals?

Thanks

---

[image: Theorem]

---

[image: Questions]

Comment: Do they prove Theorem 6.2 in the book?  If so, look and see where they needed to use the closed-ness of $[a,b]$ and see if you can "fix" that for this situation.  (And for the first one, you should have a formula for $g^{-1}$ so if you're allowed facts about fractions, you can use that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity just needs to proved at each point $x_0$. Apply the theorem to the closed interval $[- \pi/2 + \epsilon, \pi/2 - \epsilon]$, and pick $\epsilon$ small enough that $x_0$ falls in the interval.